# SQLAgent job with different schedules

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I am looking to see if its possible to have one job that runs different schedules, with the catch being one of the schedules needs to pass in a parameter.

I have an executable that will run some functionality when there is no parameter, but if there is a parameter present it will run some additional logic.

Setting up my job I created a schedule (every 15 minutes), Operating system (CmdExec)
`runApplication.exe`

For the other schedule I would like it to be once per day however the executable would need to be: `runApplication.exe "1"`

I dont think I can create a different step with a separate schedule, or can I?
Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this without having two separate jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for 2 jobs. What you can do is update your script so the result of your job (your parameter) is stored in a table. Then update your secondary logic to reference that table. If there's a value of parameter, then run your secondary logic. All in one script. If there's no value in that parameter, then have your secondary logic to return a 0 or not run at all.

Just make sure you either truncate the entire reference parameter table every run or you store a date in there so you know which one to reference.

Good luck.

Comment: Interesting idea -- one question I have is how would you write the result to a table.. given schedule 1 will run multiple times before schedule 2. How would I have it change the value for when schedule 2 was suppose to run?

Comment: You can easily do it by creating a "Parameter table". Then have a INSERT INTO Parameter table ( select result from your schedule 1). Or you can store your result in a temp table first then INSERT all in your parameter table. My scripts (at my job) does the latter.